# Writing to certain file position at Amazon.S3

Tags: amazon-s3

Does anyone know if there is a possibility to write data to certain file position that is located on Amazon.S3?

For example, how can i write 100 byte chunk of data to file on Amazon.S3 with offset of 1000 bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No I believe it's not possible to edit any file in-situ on Amazon S3 without downloading it. It's a storage space, just like your hard-disk, where you usually have to fetch the file into memory for editing and then again put it back(save it).
There are plenty of APIs available to do that. For java you have [AWS-SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/).